# Direct routing in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm currently working on a project in which the navigation layout is something like this:

```
-MAIN APPLICATION
--TAB NAVIGATOR
--- TAB 1 -> Header -> A simple button is here on the header
--- TAB 2 ...
--- TAB 3 ...
--Search Page
--Settings Page
```

I want to simply implement a direct route from that **Button** to the **Search Page**. I wonder how this could be done without any bottlenecks and pains :)
Anyone could help? What are some good implementations on the table?

Comment: Have you looked up the docs on how to navigate to other screens? And from a child to a parent or a parent to a child ... etc?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf Yeah but, react navigation provides stack navigator and etc. Haven't seen any results on changing the route from current page, directly to another page. I mean if there is no relationship between two human in reality, wouldn't it be possible for navigation to happen? :) (no Parent-Child relationships i mean)

Comment: As far as I know Search Page, Settings Page and Tab Navigator should be under one navigator (can be stack navigator, drawer navigator.. etc) to be able to navigate between them